# Failed to load remote gems: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I have used RubyMine 3.2.1 trialversion for a week now, with no errors at all. But now, when I open RubyMine I get this:

[image: failed to load remote gems]

What can I do to fix it? I am using Ruby Version Manager as well.

> spec_fetcher.rb:170: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

---

**UPDATE: I am still getting this error!**

**UPDATE 2: Not anymore!**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like some problem with the gem hosting servers, you will get the same behavior in the terminal:

```
% gem list --remote --all

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

/Users/denofevil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:170: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

In RubyMine you can disable these pop-ups in `Settings` | `Notifications` | `Gem Manager`, set to **Ignore**.

**UPDATE**: We've [filed a bug for this problem](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/137) to rubygems project.

**UPDATE 2**: The issue is resolved in RubyGems 1.8.6, run `gem update --system` to get the latest RubyGems version.

Comment: CrazyCoder: So does it mean that it will fix it self automatically? I am new to Ruby and Rails.

Comment: CrazyCoder: Thank you for updating, no more errors when launching RubyMine:)

Comment: I upgraded to rubygems 1.8.8 and this did NOT fix the error yet.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me after upgrading to rubygems 1.8.9.

Answer (score 0):

Gem upgrade to 1.8.8 fixed it for me (win7/64, ruby 1.9.2p0).

Answer (score 0):

Gem upgrade to 1.8.9 fixed it for me (MacOS 10.6 & ruby 1.9.2-p180 & rvm)